# Embedded ssrs report in react application

Tags: reactjs, reporting-services

Is there is any way, i could render ssrs report in my react application
"http://192.168.1.1/reportserver" something like that can i pass parameter of my choice!

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem to be specific to react. You should be able to use simple `<iframe src=.... />` to embed the ssrs report. Make sure you have appended `rs:Embed=true` to the reporting server query so that it allows embedding.

Comment: Thank you!
But How colud i pass the parameter

Comment: Like this? 
<iframe src="http://192.168.1.1/reportserver/reports/somereport?rs:Embed=true" >